# In Rails 3, how do I call some code via a controller but completely after the Request/Response cycle is done?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, http, resque

I have a very weird situation: I have a system where a client app (Client) makes an HTTP GET call to my Rails server, and that controller does some handling and then needs to make a separate call to the Client via a different pathway (i.e. it actually goes via Rabbit to a proxy and the proxy calls the Client). I can't change the pathway for that different call and I can't change the Client at all (it's a 3rd party system).

However: the issue is: the call via the different pathway fails UNLESS the HTTP GET from the client is completed.

So I'm trying to figure out: is there a way to have Rails *finish* the HTTP GET response *and then* make this additional call?

I've tried:

1) after_filter:  this doesn't work because the after filter is apparently still within the Request/Response cycle so the TCP/HTTP response back to the Client hasn't completed.

2) enqueuing a worker: this works, but it is not ideal because if the workers are backed up, this call back to the client may not happen right away and it really does need to happen right after the Client calls the Rails app

3) starting a separate thread: this may work, but it makes me nervous: adding threading explicitly in Rails could be fraught with peril.

I welcome any ideas/suggestions.

Again, in short, the goal is: process the HTTP GET call to the Rails app and return a 200 OK back to the Client, *completely finishing the HTTP request/response cycle* and then call some extra code

I can provide any further details if that would help. I've found both #1 and #2 as recommended options but neither of them are quite what I need.

Ideally, there would be some "after_response" callback in Rails that allows some code to run but after the full request/response cycle is done.

Comment: Most would argue #2 is the way to go, with some kind of auto-scaling worker deployment should the job enqueued_time > some_duration_you_set....

Comment: Yeah, that's the way I'm coding it now, but I really wish there was some sort of "after_response_sent" callback. It looks like I _could_ do this with ActionController::Live, but that's not in Rails 3 and the app is stuck on Rails 3 (for the time being)

Comment: There might be a way to incorporate `httparty` gem to do the get request for you in the controller?

Answer (score 0):

Possibly use an around filter? Around filters allow us to define methods that wrap around every action that rails calls. So if I had an around filter for the above controller, I could control the execution of every action, execute code before calling the action, and after calling it, and also completely skip calling the action under certain circumstances if I wanted to.

Comment: That's in interesting suggestion. I'll give it a try. I don't know if around filter will work any better than an after filter in terms of allowing me to do some code that runs truly after the whole controller request/response cycle.

Comment: Actually, the around filter still happened within the context of the request/response cycle. I couldn't figure out how to fully handle the response myself (instead of just using _yield_).

Answer (score 0):

So what I ended up doing was using a gem that I had long ago helped with:  [Spawnling](https://github.com/tra/spawnling)

It turns out that this works well, although it required a tweak to get it working with Rails 3.2. It allows me to spawn a thread to do the extra, out-of-band callback to the Client, but let the normal, controller process complete. And I don't have to worry about thread management, or AR connection management. Spawnling handles that.

It's still not ideal, but pretty close. And it's slightly better than enqueuing a Resque/Sidekiq worker as there's no risk of worker backlog causing an unexpected delay.

I still wish there was an "after_response_sent" callback or something, but I guess this is too unusual a request.

Comment: Turns out Spawnling introduced some database connection issues when the load was high. I had to scrap it for just enqueuing background workers. I'm still miffed that Rails doesn't offer any "do this after the response sent" callback. Oh well.